# How can I batch save a bunch of AppleScript scpt files to applications?

Tags: applescript

I have a bunch of AppleScript scripts in a directory that I want to be able to build as apps without having to go into each one and manually save as application.

I've already created a "build script" that used to work, but for some reason it doesn't work anymore. So I'm able to iterate through the scripts, open them in the AppleScript Editor, create the output directory, but the save command doesn't do anything anymore. Here's the relevant part:

```
on makeApp(sourcedir, outputdir, curFile)
    tell application "Finder" to set outName to name of curFile
    tell application "AppleScript Editor"
        set outNameRoot to my remove_extension(outName)
        set outAppName to outNameRoot & ".app"
        set outFileName to ((outputdir as string) & outAppName as string)
        set scriptFile to open curFile
        save scriptFile as "application" in outFileName
        --display dialog outFileName
        --close scriptFile
    end tell
end makeApp
```

The line that fails is:

```
save scriptFile as "application" in outFileName
```

This was working around September. The only thing I can think of is that I've upgraded to Lion. So my question is:

1. Does anyone know why that would fail (silently)?
2. Is there another way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **open** command is supposed to return a document, but it returns *missing value* on my machine.  You should be able to just save **document 1**, since the newly opened script will be in front.  Another option would be to use [osacompile](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/osacompile.1.html) - you don't get a bunch of script documents popping up that way.

Comment: Perfect! osacompile is just what I was looking for. Thanks